# What are the sub-sets of a null set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What are the sub-sets of a null set? I don't get any other set than `{}`. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Sanity check: a null set has $0$ elements, so its powerset had better have $2^0 = 1$ elements.

Comment: @fahad: For such a little guy, the empty set sure can cause a lot of trouble!  Visualize a set as a plastic bag, with "things" in it. One particularly simple set is the empty plastic bag.

Comment: @fahad: And earlier, I forgot to mention.  A plastic bag can have other plastic bags in it, so some or all of the **elements** of a set can be themselves sets.

Comment: Perhaps he means "null set" in the sense of measure theory, that is: a *null set* is a set of measure zero.  Not at all the same thing as the empty set.  I suspect this because he says *a* null set.

Comment: @Qiaochu I don't see how the author's slip here implies anything about his sanity.

Comment: @Doug: "Sanity check" here means (what I thought was a well-established term for) "simple test to make sure that you're on the right track." See, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_testing . It was not meant to imply anything about the author's sanity and I have no idea why you think I would say such a thing.

Comment: @Qiaochu Fair enough.  I hadn't heard of that phrase used in that way before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are right: the empty set has precisely one subset: the empty set.

As a formula: $P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}=\bigl\{\{\}\bigr\}$.

Comment: To emphasize a subtlety in Rasmus's answer, the power set of the empty set is NOT the empty set (i.e. $\emptyset$ or $\{\}$). It is the set CONTAINING the empty set (i.e. $\{\emptyset\}$ or $\{\{\}\}$). The difference is subtle and easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use the definition of "subsets".

**Definition**: Let $A$,$B$ be sets. We say that $A$ is a *subset* of $B$, denoted $A\subset B$, iff every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$, i.e.
For any object $x$, $x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B$.

Now assume that $A\subset\emptyset$, i.e., for any object $x$, $x\in A\Rightarrow x\in \emptyset$. Since $x\in\emptyset$ is always false, $x\in A$ should also be always false. And thus $A$ has to be the empty set $\emptyset$.