# Is the following statement never true or sometimes it is: $U=\emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've come up with two reasons why I'd think sometimes is true:

1. We define our universe arbitrarily: Usually we let $U=\mathbb{R}$ but that needn't be so.
2. $U=\emptyset$ means, owing to the axiom of extensionality,$\forall x\in U(x\in \emptyset)$ and $\forall y\in \emptyset(y\in U)$. The latter is triviual because $y\in \emptyset$ is an absurdity but

If providing for all object $x$ there exists a set $S$ for which $x\in S$ (I don't bear in mind wheter this is a fact or not I just don't think so),

the former is a contradiction.

Comment: at present, your question is slightly unclear, as you have not defined what qualities of $U$ you would like there to be! for instance, I suspect you do not mean the axioms of set theory, since any way of making the set $\mathbb{R}$ into a model of ZFC (ie defining a binary relation $\in_\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $(\mathbb{R},\in_\mathbb{R})\models \text{ZFC}$) would not use the structure of $\mathbb{R}$ in any organic way that I can think of. so it would be helpful if you stated what qualities you are looking for in a "universe" :)

Comment: When you say for all object $x$, do you mean for all sets $x$? If so, that statement is a direct corollary of the axiom of pairing.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom is there an instance when $U=\emptyset$ is an absurdity?

Comment: @DonThousand By $x$ I mean elements: if $x$ is not a set, is $U=\emptyset$ sometimes true?

Comment: Sets can't have elements which are not sets...

Comment: @DonThousand Because of the axiom of pairing? So, $U\ne \emptyset$?

Comment: unfortunately I am still very confused by what you are asking, but, if you *are* asking whether it is possible to make the empty set into a model of ZFC, then the answer is "no", since every model of ZFC has at least one element. (this is ensured by the axiom of the [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_empty_set).) in particular, the empty structure cannot be a model of ZFC, since it has no elements

Comment: (and in fact, many formalizations of first-order logic do not even allow there to be an empty structure, in which there is *no* first order theory that has the empty structure as a model. see eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45198/whats-the-deal-with-empty-models-in-first-order-logic) for some discussion on this point)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom That answers my questions. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: @HannyBoy my pleasure, very happy it helped!!! :)